# Why do I get segmentation error when calling a parsing function in C

Tags: c, linux

I have been trying to understand how this custom function below works to parse lines from argv but I keep getting segmentation errors.
I have been trying to debug it for hours but I cannot find the bug that is eating into "restricted memory"
The function takes a string literal and a delimiter string (not character).

When I use `valgrind` to audit the function, it reports a SIGSEGV error when calling strtok.

I understand strtok cannot work directly with string literals because it can cause undefined behaviour. So I decided to copy the `str` to a local variable first.

Yes, I tried using an array as copy too, but it still throws the segmentation error.

What I really don't understand is why does strtok not getting enough memory?

```
char **splitstring(char *str, const char *delim)
{
    int i, wn;
    char **array;
    char *token;
    char *copy;

    copy = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (copy == NULL)
    {
        perror("hsh");
        return (NULL);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        copy[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    copy[i] = '\0';

    token = strtok(copy, delim);
    array = malloc((sizeof(char *) * 2));
    array[0] = strdup(token);

    i = 1;
    wn = 3;
    while (token)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        array = realloc(array, (sizeof(char *) * (wn - 1)), (sizeof(char *) * wn));
        array[i] = strdup(token);
        i++;
        wn++;
    }
    free(copy);
    return (array);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you write your own copying loop instead of using `strcpy`? Or use `strdup` like you do later.

Comment: And what strange [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) do you have that takes three arguments? Also remember that (the standard) `realloc` can fail and then return `NULL`. Which will your code loose the original (but still valid) pointer.

Comment: Furthermore, how will the function calling `splitstring` know how many elements are in the array it returns?

Comment: sorry, that was a custom realloc. I edited it for posting here to avoid posting unnecessary code, but the custom realloc works very well.

Comment: `token = strtok(NULL, delim);` is placed wrong... you don't check the value of `token` afterwards but just use it in `array[i] = strdup(token);` The "pattern" for use of `strtok` is that `token = strtok(NULL, delim);` is to be the last statement in the `while` loop. By doing that `while(token)` will ensure that you don't carry on when `token` becomes NULL

Comment: Please don't name your custom functions the same as standard functions. That make the code harder to read, understand, maintain and debug.

Comment: "but the custom realloc works very well"  How do you know? Because your code does apparently not work at all and that realloc call looks very fishy.

Comment: See [mcve] ....

Comment: @SupportUkraine true, the order of execution of the lines inside the while loop was wrong, just changed and it does work now. The only issue is that the first and the second string are similar in the returned array. But I can solve that now.

Comment: @Lundin yes, I am sure my custom realloc works because I have tested it with several test suites calling it from a different function. but thanks.

Comment: @JaredAtandi When you move `token = strtok(NULL, delim);` to be the last statement in the `while`, you'll also have to do minor changes to the code that use `token`

Comment: @JaredAtandi Here is a simple and typical way of using `strtok` in a `while` loop: https://ideone.com/7t3e53

Comment: Betcha think you've got a "NULL terminated array of pointers" (like `argv[]`) Betcha haven't...